# Simple question about dummy variables

Tags: statistics

I have a regression where I include several groups of dummy variables: race “white” and “black” in my regression and "other" if both "black" and "white" are equal to 0. Where can I find the coefficient for “other”? In my regression I also included other dummy variables (whether bachelor, graduate or highschool or no highschool (the last being excluded)). How do I find the coefficients for both “other” race and “no highschool” in the same regression?

Comment: You have $a+b\cdot\text{black}+c\cdot\text{white}$.  So $a$ is the coefficient when both black and white are zero.

Comment: and in a stata output where do I read that? Is it true that the coefficient in front of the other dummies tells you the effect compared to the one not shown? so if black = 8% then that means that blacks are 8% more likely then "other" to buy icecream when it is sunny

Comment: Yes, it's the reference category.